# Отображение hex C-строки (cout << hex << int(char)) C++

Tags: c++, преобразование, преобразование-типов

Есть функция, которая выводит  hex C-строку, может есть более правильный способ?

```
void outHexByCout(const char * cha, int len)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        cout  << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << static_cast<uShort>(cha[i]) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Пример вывода:

> 00 1f ff80 00 00 00 03 ffac 00 15 5b 30 33 2d 32 38 20 32 31 3a 35 37
>   3a 31 30 3a 31 30 30 5d 00

Что нужно:

> 00 1F 80 00 00 00 03 AC 00 15 5B 30 33 2D 32 38 20 32 31 3A 32 31 3A
>   30 30 3A 31 30 30 5D 00

Почему приписывает **ff**?
Например, вот эту строчку получил

> ff80 00 00 00

таким образом:

```
...
writeSESS(128);
...
        void writeSESS(uint32_t ses)const
        {
            // const char* m_buffer 
            memcpy(const_cast<char*>(m_buffer + 2, (char*)&ses, sizeof(uint32_t)); 
        }
```

Comment: Вам надо сначала преобразовать char в unsigned char  static_cast<unsigned char>( cha[I] ) перед преобразованием в unsigned short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш компилятор в соответствии с установленными опциями рассматривает тип `char` аналогично типу `signed char`, поэтому при приведении типов знаковый бит объекта распространяется на старшие биты результирующего выражения.

Сравните.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    char c = '\x80';

    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>( c )  << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned short>( static_cast<unsigned char>( c ) )  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы

```
ff80
80
```

Вам надо сначала объект типа `char` преобразовывать в объект типа `unsigned char`, а лишь затем в тип `unsigned short` или `short`